# R: how to use the aggregate()-function to sum data from one column if another column has a distinct value?

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

Hei,
I have a problem with the aggregate-function. My data looks like this:

```
 transect_id    year    day month   LST precipitation   
 1  TR001   2010    191 4   30.62083    0.0000  
 2  TR001   2010    191 4   30.62083    0.0003  
 3  TR001   2010    191 5   30.62083    0.0001  
 4  TR001   2010    191 7   30.62083    0.0000  
 5  TR001   2010    191 7   30.62083    0.0000  
 6  TR001   2011    191 7   30.62083    0.0007
```

and I want to sum the precipitation for each quartal of each year. Which means: sum precipitation for months 1-3, months 4-6, 7-9 and 10-12 for every year (in my case 2010-2013). And add a column for it.
I figured that I should use the mutate()-function from the plyr-package and then do something like

```
weather_gam.mutated<-mutate(weather_gam, precipitation.spring=aggregate(precipitation by = list(Category=year)))
```

but what to do for the months? I simply can't figure it out. I tried stuff like `by = list(Category= month==1)` but obviously that's not what it takes to succeed here. 
So basically I just try to do what `SUMIFS(F1:Fx, B1:Bx = "2010", D1:Dx = "1", D1:Dx = "2", D1:Dx = "3"` would do in Excel, just I hope that by setting

```
by = list(Category=year)
```

It will automatically always sum when the year is the same so I don't need to do it manually for every year. 
I really would appreciate any help here, also if you have a completely different idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `dplyr` and `lubridate`; the idea is to use the `quarter` function of `lubridate` to find out at which quarter months belong to. Create the `Quarter` column, group by Quarter and create the Sum or `precipitation` for each group.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df$month <- month(df$month)
df %>% mutate(Quarter = quarter(month)) %>% group_by(Quarter) %>% mutate(SumPre = sum(precipitation))

Source: local data frame [6 x 8]
Groups: Quarter

  transect_id year day month      LST precipitation Quarter SumPre
1       TR001 2010 191     4 30.62083         0e+00       2  4e-04
2       TR001 2010 191     4 30.62083         3e-04       2  4e-04
3       TR001 2010 191     5 30.62083         1e-04       2  4e-04
4       TR001 2010 191     7 30.62083         0e+00       3  7e-04
5       TR001 2010 191     7 30.62083         0e+00       3  7e-04
6       TR001 2011 191     7 30.62083         7e-04       3  7e-04
```

and here another approach with `aggregate`

```
library(lubridate)
df$month <- month(df$month)
df$Quarter <- quarter(df$month)
aggregate(precipitation ~ Quarter, data = df, sum)
Quarter precipitation
1       2         4e-04
2       3         7e-04
```

### data

```
df <- structure(list(transect_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "TR001", class = "factor"), year = c(2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L), day = c(191L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 
191L, 191L), month = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L), LST = c(30.62083, 
30.62083, 30.62083, 30.62083, 30.62083, 30.62083), precipitation = c(0, 
3e-04, 1e-04, 0, 0, 7e-04)), .Names = c("transect_id", "year", 
"day", "month", "LST", "precipitation"), row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sorry for not replying so far, I was in the field. This way it works perfectly, thanks! It's amazing how there's a package for everything in R :)

Comment: @jewish.cowboy you are welcome, and welcome to SO. Do not forget to accept and/or upvote the best answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

use dplyr instead of plyr:

```
library(dplyr)

d.in %>%
    mutate(q=cut(month, c(0,3,6,9,12), labels=c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"))) %>%
    group_by(year, q) %>%
    mutate(sum.prec = sum(precipitation))
```